# make my password generator generate 'complex' passwords

Tags: vb.net, passwords

I've got a password generator in one of my scripts which generates 2 passwords and writes them to a database.

These passwords are later retrieved and set as the windows logon passwords for 2 users which are automatically created in a virtual machine.

I have a problem whereby my passwords are not always considered to be complex as far as windows is concerned.

I am using the following function to generate my passwords...

```
    Public Function GeneratePassword(ByVal len As Integer) As String
    Dim str As String = "1234567890qwertyuio1pa2sd3fg4hj5kl6zx7cv8bn9mQ0WE1RT2YU3IO4PA5SD6FG7HJ8KL9ZX0CVBNM"
    Dim N As Integer = str.Length
    Dim rnd As New Random((Now.Hour * 3600 + Now.Minute * 60 +
    Now.Second) * 1000 + Now.Millisecond)
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    For l As Integer = 1 To len
    sb.Append(str.Substring(rnd.Next(0, N), 1))
    Next
    Return sb.ToString
    End Function
```

Which is then called like this...

```
    Dim vm_password1 As String = GeneratePassword(10)
```

How would i best go about modifying this code to ensure that each password generated contains 1 uppercase character, 1 lowercase character and one number?

Any help appreciated! :)

Comment: split your string into multiple strings. One for capital letters, one for numbers etc. Then make sure you get at least one item from each of those strings when you make your password

Comment: Don't use the `Random` class for security related matters (please see my other [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21454915/make-my-password-generator-generate-complex-passwords#comment32390472_21455648)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can extend this further, but here's the jist

```
Public Function fnGenPw() As String

    Dim RandomClass As New Random()
    Const legalAlpha As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    Const legalNums As String = "1234567890"

    Dim strbNewpw As New StringBuilder

    For i As Integer = 0 To 2 'first 3 characters are alpha
        Dim RandomNumber As Integer = RandomClass.Next(legalAlpha.Length - 1)
        strbNewpw.Append(legalAlpha.Chars(RandomNumber))
    Next
    For i As Integer = 3 To 5 'characters 4,5,6 are numeric
        Dim RandomNumber As Integer = RandomClass.Next(legalNums.Length - 1)
        strbNewpw.Append(legalNums.Chars(RandomNumber))
    Next
    For i As Integer = 6 To 9 'characters 7,8,9,10 are alpha
        Dim RandomNumber As Integer = RandomClass.Next(legalAlpha.Length - 1)
        strbNewpw.Append(legalAlpha.Chars(RandomNumber))
    Next

    Return strbNewpw.ToString
End Function
```

Comment: It should be using [RNGCryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) otherwise the generated values are predicatble and therefore insecure.

Comment: Its really not that big of an issue at this stage as the user accounts which are created have the 'user must change password at first logon' set, so this generated password is just one which will be sent to the customer via secure ticket for their initial logon to windows, after which they are forced to pick a complex password of their own. :)